# Possible to print list items hidden by Jquery "slideup" function

Tags: jquery, printing, hidden, slideup

i'm trying to get this accordion to expand when printed. the code degrades gracefully when javascript is turned off, but it just doesn't expand when printing.

here's a demo of it so you can see how it works: http://evanmoore.webs.com/test.htm

thank you so much for your help!

below is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
    .accordionContainer ul li {
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>

<script src="http://visualjquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
var intDefaultOpenIndex = 0;
$(".accordion li h2").next().slideUp(100);
$(".accordion li").eq(intDefaultOpenIndex).addClass("expanded").children("h2").next().slideDown(100);
$(".accordion li h2").click(function() {
if ($(this).parent().hasClass('expanded'))  {
$(this).parent().removeClass('expanded').find("ul").slideUp(100);
$(this).parent().removeClass('expanded').find("p").slideUp(100);
} else {

$(".accordion .expanded ul").slideUp(100).parent().removeClass('expanded');
$(this).parent().addClass('expanded').find("ul").slideDown(100);
$(".accordion .expanded p").slideUp(100).parent().removeClass('expanded');
$(this).parent().addClass('expanded').find("p").slideDown(100);
$(".accordion .expanded form").slideUp(100).parent().removeClass('expanded');
}

});
});

//-->
</script>

<div class="accordionContainer">

<ul class="accordion">

 <li><h2>Title 1</h2>
  <ul>
   <li>Content 1</li>
   <li>Content 2</li>
   <li>Content 3</li>   
  </ul>
 </li>

 <li><h2>Related Programs</h2>
  <p>content 1</p>
 </li>
 <li><h2>Why APU</h2>
  <p>content 3</p>
 </li>
 <li><h2>About the University</h2>
  <p>content 4</p>
 </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `!important` to force the CSS rule to override the `style` property, like this:  (Untested)

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
    .accordionContainer ul li {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried doing exactly that and it didn't work. I'm under the impression that a special class needs to be added to the javascript that becomes "executed" in a way when the @media print is triggered.

Comment: i tried IE7, firefox 3 and safari for example. i added the media print with ".accordionContainer ul li" as an example not knowing if it was correct -- was i though?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the Accordion to expand for printing, why are you setting it to `display:none;` if the media is `print`? (as SLaks, `display: hide;` does nothing.)

Seems to me like you should actually be setting display to 'inline' or 'block' depending on it's usage through the rest of the page. A list-item defaults to 'inline' so if you haven't made a change in your CSS, then I'd set it to that.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (put at the end of the CSS file where screen styles are)

```
.ui-accordion-content {
    display: block !important;
}
```